# Making a String from KeyTyped in Java

Tags: java, tostring, keyevent

I must make a nickname, and I do everything, using KeyListener. I want to write nickname using keyTyped, but I have no idea, how to save each letter. For exaple:

```
keyTyped(KeyEvent e){           
        char key = e.getKeyChar();
        nick = new String[10];
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            nick[i] = Character.toString(key);
            key = e.getKeyChar();
        }
 }
```

Unfortunately, every letter is the last one typed. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because `e.getKeyChar()` only pulls the char that has been pressed, it doesn't get a new char every time. Therefore the array is always just the character 10 times. Does your nickname need to be an array? Because if it doesn't, you can do something like this (which also means, if you get rid of the if statement then the nickname can be as long as you like):

```
int count = 0;
String nick = ""; 
keyTyped (KeyEvent e){
        char key = e.getKeyChar;
        //If your nickname needs to be only 10 characters long, then this
        //Stops too many characters from entering
        if (count < 10){

            nick += key
        }
}
```

Comment: Does `+=` work with strings? If not use `nick.concat(key)`

Answer (score 0):

Every time a key is typed the for loop runs, making every letter in the array the last one typed, as you say. Define a counter variable outside the keyTyped event, use it as your array location, and then increment it each time a key is typed. Also define the nickname outside the keyTyped event.

```
int count = 0;
nick = new String[10];
keyTyped(KeyEvent e){           
        if(count<nick.length) { //make sure if more than 10 characters are pressed it wont cause an error
            char key = e.getKeyChar();
            nick[count] = Character.toString(key);
            count += 1;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the "for" loop is being executed everytime when you take the character from keyboard. Each time variable i is being set to 0 and the last character is being placed in array of string.

initialize loop variable before taking the character from keyboard.

I hope this resolved your issue.